# Do Silverlight or WPF applications use Direct2D or DirectWrite to render fonts and UI?

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer-9, direct2d, directwrite

I found a lot of information that IE9 uses DirectWrite and Direct2D instead of GDI for rendering UI. Is the same true for WPF and Silverlight applications?

Answer (score 2):

WPF renders on top of Direct3D 9 (preventing the use of Direct2D), but they do still use DirectWrite for the text rendering as of WPF 4.0 on Windows 7 ([ref](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2010/03/05/additional-wpf-text-clarity-improvements.aspx#9973975)). Since DirectWrite exists separately from Direct2D, they are able to use the lower-level interfaces to DirectWrite and reimplement the rendering on top of Direct3D 9, similarly to how Direct2D provides its text acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

No, WPF works on top of DirectX 9.

Comment: WPF 4.0 adopted DirectWrite around 2011, just not Direct2D ("The WPF text rendering stack has been completely replaced" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb613588(v=vs.100).aspx#text). Some of the developers working DirectWrite even came from WPF. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/04/13/directwrite-questions-and-answers.aspx

Comment: @DwayneRobinson Could you help with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23173303/color-emoji-support-in-winforms-wpf-application