# Color Emoji support in Winforms/WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, emoji

I'd like to build a Windows application that supports Windows 8.1's color emoji. What I can't seem to find actually stated anywhere, but seems to be the case, is that this isn't possible unless you're building a "Windows Store" application, which of course requires a paid developer license. Oh boy, it's iOS development all over again!

So anyway, is there a way to develop in either WinForms or WPF which will allow color emoji while running on Windows 8.1?

Comment: The colored glyphs can be found in the family Segoe UI Emoji. If it isn't set as a fallback on desktop apps, see if setting `FontFamily` to that will work on WPF.

Comment: That works fine for the black and white glyphs, but it still doesn't show the new color ones.

Comment: Hmm. The black and white glyphs are in Segoe UI - at least on Windows 7 - unless Windows just insists on displaying those instead of the color ones on the desktop even if the Emoji variant is used.

Comment: Well I gave it another quick try, and sure enough, color emoji work **perfectly** in any control...if I create a Windows Store project. No extra effort required. But that doesn't really help. I really don't get why setting the font to Segoe UI Emoji doesn't work for WinForms/WPF.

Comment: Getting color emoji support requires targeting the DirectWrite api and Windows 8.  Neither Winforms nor WPF expose it.  DirectWrite is the kind of api that a UI team with dozens of programmers targets, using C++.  The liability of using a friendly class library is that you're stuck with what it is willing to support.  Which invariable is not bleeding edge features that require the latest operating system version.  Maybe some day if the WPF team wakes up again.

Comment: can this question be revisited? is it still actually impossible to get color emoji in a WPF app?

Comment: @Julien: The closest thing I've found is to individually replace each emoji character in a string with an image, which in WinForms means using a RichTextBox (I haven't explored WPF much, maybe there's an alternative there?). It's not a wonderfully-pleasant way to make it work, but Twitter's web interface does this.

Comment: @Amazingant We're using emoji in our WPF application and it needs to be vector, we can't use images. Any other solution?

Comment: @SepehrM I'd suggest posting that as a new question, but I'll answer here anyway. IIRC, on Apple and Android devices, emoji glyphs are PNGs embedded in the font, and so aren't vector-based anyway. I believe Windows 8.1 uses vector-based glyphs instead, but I don't know for sure. My best suggestion would be to use multiple versions of each emoji at different resolutions and change between them as the font size changes, or to see if you can use a vector-based image format such as SVG in WPF (never tried this, so I can't help there).

Comment: @SepehrM It's not a wonderful solution, but using multiple versions of each emoji seems to work well enough on iOS and OS X, so with a bit of work I think you could make it look acceptable.

Comment: @SepehrM I don't know enough about interop with WPF to write a real answer, but if you can render a single DWRITE_GLYPH_RUN, then on Windows 8.1 you could call TranslateColorGlyphRun to decompose the original glyph run into multiple layers of different colors (each a vector glyph run). e.g. https://gist.github.com/makotokato/9458865

Comment: @DwayneRobinson Thanks, but that will complicate matters. We wanted to use color fonts because of their ease of use. I think we'll just convert the svg image of the characters and convert them to XAML `Path`s.

Answer (score 6):

As of .NET 4.6.1, you can't out of the box. Color emojis don't work in WPF. They do on XAML Universal Windows apps, but WPF specifically they do not.

You only solution right now is to do some UI layer processing that inserts an image of your choice for every emoji you want to be displayed in color. It's a crappy process but that's all you got right now.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try Emoji.Wpf library:

[https://github.com/samhocevar/emoji.wpf](https://%20Emoji%20rendering%20support%20to%20WPF%20applications)

It seems it does exactly what you need, adds rendering support for emoji to WPF applications.